# Properties of limits

Tags: limits

If we have a limit of the form:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a(x)-b}{c(x)}$$

Is it always possible to write it as $$-\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{b-a(x)}{c(x)}$$

Can this always be done, or must parts of the expression be/not be functions of $x$?

Edit: the question is motivated by the math in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/236814/126012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an allowed property of limits. Recall

$$\lim_{x \to a} k\cdot f(x) = k\cdot \lim_{x \to a} f(x),$$

So, in your original limit, you can factor out the numerator of the fraction to be:
$$a(x)-b=-1\cdot(b-a(x))$$

Now, using Eqn.1, you can simply take out the constant multiple of -1 from the original limit.

Answer (score 1):

If limits $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ exist, then limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x)$ also exists.

Take $f(x)=\frac{a(x)-b}{c(x)}$ and $g(x)=-1$.

So, by multiplying the initial limit twice with $-1$, you get the result you want.

Comment: Why bother defining the constant multiple as a function, instead of just simply using the law for a scalar multiple?

Comment: Because that's what I came up with! :)

Comment: Okay, just making sure I was not missing something.